# Running script on all columns in excel/VBA

Tags: vba, http, excel, put

So, I have an HTTP PUT request that I need to run on a large amount of data. (50,000+ cells)

All of this is contained in two rows, and about 25,000 columns. First row is the HTTP URL to PUT to, the second is data that will be part of a larger string as the request.

Assuming the first two columns of my sheet are as follows, where the cells are separated via comma

```
Location1, Sample Data 1
Location2, Sample Data 2
```

I will be sending a PUT request to domain.com/API/Location1 containing the string "data=Sample Data 1" where "domain.com/API/" Is a constant and "data=" is also a constant.

Not knowing enough about excel, I just created a button to call my code. I am still figuring out how to insert cell data into this code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

URL = "https://domain.com/api/Location1" 
DATA = "here_is_a_long_string_specifying_the_value_to_modify=Sample Data 1"
   Set HTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
   HTTP.Open "PUT", URL, False
   HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   HTTP.send REQUEST

End Sub
```

Ultimately I would like it to do something like URL = ""(1,x)

Then proceed through the list so (1,1) then 1,2 and 1,3, etc..

I am unsure where to direct my searches at this point

Comment: Do you really have 25k columns?  I thought the max was ~16k.

Comment: It is all contained on multiple sheets. This was an approximation to show how big this project is.

Thanks for the edit by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got my script working

```
x=0
While x < 25000
x = (x + 1)
URL = "https://domain.com/api/" Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
DATA = "string_of_data=" Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
   set HTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
   HTTP.Open "PUT", URL, False, "Login", "Password"
   HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   HTTP.send DATA
wend
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this might help:

Getting cell data in Excel VBA:

```
cells(rowindex,columnindex).value

URL = "https://domain.com/api/" & cells(1,1).value
DATA = "yaddayadda=" & cells(2,1).value
```

Add a for loop to this, and u're good to go:

```
For i = 1 To Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column 'assuming your cells are continously filled
 URL = "https://domain.com/api/" & Cells(1, i).Value
 DATA = "yaddayadda=" & Cells(2, i).Value
Next i
```

The

```
Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
```

part finds the column number of the last filled cell starting from cell A1, going right.

Hope this helps, and I didn't completely misunderstand your question. :)

Comment: Also, you might wanna transpose your data, Excel is longer down than it is wide across.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a ton for your response. I will try this later. I posted my own answer as well in case you wanted to see my approach. Mine is a bit archaic, Hoping I can put yours to use and learn something new in the process